# Evaluate the size of the diagonals of parallelogram constructed on the vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

$\vec a = 5\vec p + 2 \vec q$,

$\vec b = \vec p - 3 \vec q$,

$\mid \vec p \mid = 2\sqrt{2}$

$\mid \vec q \mid = 3$

$\angle (\vec p,\vec q) = \frac{\pi }{4}$

Ok, I know that $\vec p \cdot \vec q = 3 \cdot 2\sqrt{2}\cdot cos(\frac{\pi }{4}) = 6$.

But I dont know what is the meaning of Dot product and how can I use this,
Someone can help me or give me a hint ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
$$\vec a \cdot \vec b=(5 \vec p + 2 \vec q)(\vec p -3 \vec q)=5p^2-13 \vec p \vec q-6 q^2=40-78-54=-92$$
$$a^2=|\vec a|^2=(5 \vec p + 2 \vec q )^2=25p^2+20 \vec p \vec q+4 q^2=200+120+36=356 \Rightarrow |\vec a|=\sqrt{356}$$
$$b^2=|\vec b|^2=(\vec p -3 \vec q )^2=p^2-6 \vec p \vec q+9 q^2=8-36+81=53 \Rightarrow |\vec b|=\sqrt{53}$$
$$\cos (\vec a, \vec b)=\frac{\vec a \cdot \vec b}{|\vec a||\vec b|}$$

$$d_{1,2}^2=a^2+b^2\pm 2|\vec a |\cdot|\vec b|\cos (\vec a, \vec b)$$

Comment: Can you explain the last line ?

Comment: The theorem of cosines

Comment: It has to be, $a^2 + b^2 + 2\cdot \mid \vec p \mid \cdot \mid \vec q \mid \cdot cos(\vec a ,\vec b)$ ,No ?

Comment: No, $d^2=a^2+b^2 \pm 2\vec {a} \vec {b}$

Comment: $p^{2} = 64$ ? it has to be $8$ No ? $(2\sqrt{2})^{2} = 8$.

Comment: $p^2=(2\sqrt2)^2=(\sqrt8)^2=8$

Comment: I know, you wrote in the first line that $5p^{2} = 320$,What is wrong.

Comment: I made a mistake, corrected

Comment: Thanks,But can you explain me about the last line please ?

Comment: $\triangle ABC: AB=c, BC=a, CA=b, \angle BAC=\alpha$
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos \alpha$$